# How to get value from object in document using MondoDB driver C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I have data stored in MongoDB like below:

```
_id:5e72196fa7e42815ece552c0
dates: Object
   StartDate:2020-06-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
status:"Active"
```

My Custom Class is like below:

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

So using the below code I'm getting Status but not Date.

```
var projection = Builders<Entity>.Projection
                                .Exclude(x => x.Id)
                                .Include(x => x.Status)
                                .Include(x => x.Dates.StartDate);
 var data = await _collection.Find(FilterDefination).Project<MyCustomClass>(projection).FirstAsync();
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

First this kind of projection is an aggregate projection. I had to move it into an `Aggregate`:

```
dummies.Aggregate().Match(FilterDefinition<Entity>.Empty).Project(...)
```

Even than it didn't work, because C# driver didn't handle the projection well:

```
var projection = new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<Entity>().Include("$dates.StartDate");
// throws MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'..'
var data = dummies.Aggregate().Match(FilterDefinition<Entity>.Empty).Project(projection).FirstAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Final result is using `BsonDocumentProjectionDefinition`:

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("inner");
var dummies = db.GetCollection<Entity>("Dummy");
//dummies.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse("{dates: {StartDate: new Date(\"2020-06-01\")}, status: \"Active\"}"));

var projection = new BsonDocumentProjectionDefinition<Entity, MyCustomClass>(BsonDocument.Parse("{\"StartDate\": \"$dates.StartDate\", _id: 0, status: 1}"));
var data = dummies.Aggregate().Match(FilterDefinition).Project(projection).FirstAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```